# DIY liquid piston

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

.

Hi everyone,

I'm working on a DIY project and experimenting with the arrangements shown in the image below. Basically, we have a container full of water that is exposed to the atmosphere. There is also an empty cylinder that is sealed on one end, where a pressure gauge is attached.

[image]

I'm not a physicist, but I do know that for a gas in a closed container, reducing the volume increases the pressure (regardless of whether this is being done isothermally or adiabatically).

Accordingly, case #3 is puzzling me. In case 3, the volume of air inside the cylinder is obviously shrinking, but surprisingly the pressure stays the same!  Regardless of how deep I move the tube, the pressure gauge doesn't change.  The water height doesn't change either, both outside and inside the cylinder, so the pressure in the cylinder is indeed equal to 1 atm

I also thought the air might be dissolving in the water due to the pressure increase, but the solubility of air in water (at room temperature, and up to 40 psig) is less than 5% (volume-wise), so this can't be the reason.

The gauge is working (tested with a compressor), and the seals are good (tested with soap+water).

Comment: What type of pressure gauge: absolute or gauge?

Comment: its a gauge pressure ...

Comment: So in Case#1, you expect the pressure inside the open cylinder to be 1 atmosphere greater than the pressure outside the open cylinder?

Comment: Obviously the pressure must increase because your decreasing the volume. It must be the gauge. Is it measuring in increments of 1atm to 2 atm etc? The new pressure is somewhere in between. Maybe the gauge is not sensitive enough.

Comment: @josephh I also had a feeling it might not be sensitive enough, but then I pushed almost the whole cylinder into the water, in order to maximize the pressure and get a reading ... still nothing, pressure didn't change a bit (the range is 0 to 60 psi, so I guess it should be sensitive enough)

Comment: @DJohnM you're right .. I'm using a gauge pressure, but the numbers reported in the figure are absolute.  Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 3):

You must have a leak. The water levels inside and outside will not remain even if there is no leak. Take a clear drinking glass or a clear jar that you are sure has no holes in it. invert it and push it down in the water. You will see that the levels do not remain even. With no leaks the pressure inside the cylinder will increase by about 1.47 PSI per meter of depth. This will give you half the volume of air and 2 atm pressure  in the cylinder as is shown or expected in figure 3 but at a depth of about 10 meters, not level with the surface.

Comment: I will re-test it for leaks and double check again. Can you please clarify how you obtained the 1.47 PSI figure? Wouldn't the obtained pressure depend on the size of the cylinder? Say we have two cylinders:  cylinder A (volume = 1000 cm3), and cylinder B (volume = 1 cm3).   If we then push both cylinders to a depth of 0.5 cm into the water, this would halve the volume of cylinder B (hence double the pressure), but would not change the volume of A that much (hence the pressure would remain the same) .. therefore the induced pressure can not be a function of depth only, right?

Comment: I didn't get the last two lines of your comment.  Why would the volume of air be halved only at exactly 10 meters? If I push a drinking glass down a bucket of water, I can halve the volume of air in the glass by pushing it down just around 5-10 [**centi**]meters or so, without having to go all the way down to 10 meters.

Comment: Water pressure increases with depth. Impurities and temperature can slightly affect water density, but the pressure increase is about 1.47 psi per meter of depth

Comment: Yes, I do know that water pressure increases with depth, but in this case I do not know which physical phenomenon will ultimately determine the air pressure in the cylinder. I guess I can rephrase the question like this:   is it (A) air pressure in the cylinder is determined **exclusively** based on the hydrostatic pressure of the water at the bottom of the cylinder (following the equation P = pgh)? or (B) air pressure in the cylinder is determined **exclusively** by the reduction of the volume of they air in the cylinder (following the ideal gas law PV=nRT)?

Comment: They are linear, as pressure increases volume decreases. Every ten meters of water depth increases pressure by about 1 atmosphere.

Comment: A specific volume of air at 1 atm compressed to 2 atm will be about half its original volume.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a leak, and the description below attempts to prove it.

One thing we can be almost sure of **not** being wrong is the gauge.
Because if the pressure inside the cylinder was indeed **$1 \ \text{atm}$ more than outside**, **you would feel a significant upward force** even for a cylinder of very small cross section area. E.g. for a cylinder of radius 5 cm, the upward force would be:
$$\begin{align}
F &= \Delta P \times area\\
&=1atm \times \pi \times.05 \times.05\\
&=101325 \times 3.14 \times .0025\\
&\approx795 \ \text{Newtons} \\& \approx 75 \ \text{kg !}
\end{align}
$$

When we push something like a cylinder in your question in water, say by depth $d$, the air does get compressed, but this compression is just enough to increase the pressure so that the new pressure matches the pressure in water at the depth $d$. **That's the necessary condition for the equilibrium of water level**.

Let's say your cylinder has length $L$, cross-sectional area $A$, the new length of air column in the cylinder is $l$, and density of water $\rho$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
P_{atm} \times V_{initial} &= P_{new} \times V_{new} \\
\text{Or, } P_{atm} \times L \times A &  = (P_{atm} + \rho dg) \times l \times A \\
\text{Hence, } l &= \frac{P_{atm} \times L}{P_{atm} + \rho dg} \\
 &= \frac{L}{1 + \frac{\rho dg}{P_{atm}}}
\end{align}
$$
So, for $l$ to be half of $L$, $\rho dg$ should be equal to $P_{atm}$. On plugging in the values, we get $d$ to be about $10m$.

And, in that case, the pressure inside the cylinder should be $2atm$, in which case you should have observed three things:

1. A considerable upward force on the cylinder;
2. The cylinder would be submerged by about $10m$; and
3. Water rising up to half the length of the cylinder.

If these are not happening, and in fact, the water level is not changing at all, there must be a leak.

**Note**: There is an approximation used in the calculation above.
The statement "...compression is just enough to increase the pressure so that the new pressure matches the pressure in water at the depth $d$" assumes that the rise of water column ($x$) inside the cylinder will be small enough so that we can ignore it.

In exact terms, "the new pressure of the air should match the water pressure at a depth of $(d-x)$". Shall be grateful if someone can present the exact calculations.